# equivalent of gtk's expander in pyqt4

Tags: pyqt4

Is there a container in qt4 that can exapdn or collapse and hide its children, like GtkExpander?

[image: gtk expander from the docs]

The qt4 designer has exactly that, but it appears to be a custom widget:

[image: qt4 designer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but it is fairly easy to implement one. Here is a very basic example. You can extend it with more functionality:

[image]

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class ExpanderWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, widget, parent=None):
        super(ExpanderWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        # better use your own icons
        # these are kind of ugly :)
        style = QtGui.QCommonStyle()
        self.rightArrow = style.standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_ArrowRight)
        self.downArrow = style.standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_ArrowDown)

        self.toggle = QtGui.QPushButton(self.downArrow, text)
        self.toggle.clicked.connect(self.toggleWidget)

        self.widget = widget

        self.layout.addWidget(self.toggle)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def toggleWidget(self):
        if self.widget.isVisible():
            self.toggle.setIcon(self.rightArrow)
            self.widget.setVisible(False)
        else:
            self.toggle.setIcon(self.downArrow)
            self.widget.setVisible(True)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

secretWidget = QtGui.QLabel('I am a secret widget. I can be hidden!')

expander = ExpanderWidget('I hide a widget', secretWidget)
expander.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```